# How to implement dynamic multi language Recaptcha v2 in nextjs application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recaptcha, next.js, i18next

I am using next.js with [next-i18next](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next) to handle translations on my page.

I am using [react-google-recaptcha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-recaptcha) for google recaptcha, but I can use it without the package if it is easier.

When user wants to change language we have a dropdown with language selection and we call `props.i18n.changeLanguage(newLanguage)` to update the language.

Example code. Problem is that even though language changes the recaptcha does not change.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ReCAPTCHA from 'react-google-recaptcha';

export default class RecaptchaWrapper extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    language: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    const { language } = this.props;
    if (!language) {
      return null;
    }

    return <ReCAPTCHA hl={language} sitekey="secret" onChange={() => {}} />;
  }
}
```